# Xmarin Forms to MAUI Upgrade - Doubled Navigation Bar on Android

Tags: xamarin, maui

I am in the process of porting a Shell Based Xamarin Forms app to Maui and have a UI issue where the Navigation bar is being displayed twice. The second bar is correctly styled but there is a purple bar above it that I seem to have no control over and can't remove. This did not exist in the Xamarin Forms version of the app

[image]

The app is a Shell Based app and the code for this is here:

```
<Shell xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ISAI.Lessons.Mobile.Views"
       Title="ISAI.Lessons.Mobile"
       x:Class="ISAI.Lessons.Mobile.AppShell">

    <Shell.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
                <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
            <Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
   

            <Style Class="FlyoutItemLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"></Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style Class="FlyoutItemLayoutStyle" TargetType="Layout" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                    <VisualStateGroupList>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                      `enter code here`          <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateGroupList>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style Class="MenuItemLayoutStyle" TargetType="Layout" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
                <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                    <VisualStateGroupList>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateGroupList>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Shell.Resources>


    <ShellContent 
        Route="LaunchPage" 
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LaunchPage}"
   
        >
    </ShellContent>

    <FlyoutItem Title="Home" Icon="outline_home_black_18.png" >
        <ShellContent Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}"  />
    </FlyoutItem>

    <FlyoutItem Title="Lessons" Icon="outline_cast_for_education_black_18.png">
        <ShellContent Route="LessonGroupPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LessonGroupPage}"  />
    </FlyoutItem>

    <FlyoutItem Title="Lesson Downloads" Icon="outline_file_download_black_18.png">
        <ShellContent Route="LessonDownloadsPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LessonDownloadsPage}"  />
    </FlyoutItem>

    <MenuItem Text="Logout" StyleClass="MenuItemLayoutStyle" Clicked="OnMenuItemClicked" IconImageSource="outline_logout_black_18.png">
    </MenuItem>

    <TabBar>
        <ShellContent Route="LoginPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" />
    </TabBar>


    <TabBar>
        <ShellContent Route="LessonsPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LessonsPage}" />
    </TabBar>

    

</Shell>
```

My main activity code is here:

```
 [Activity(
        Theme = "@style/MainTheme", 
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]
    public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            //TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            //ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            DependencyService.Register<IHud, Hud>();
            DependencyService.Register<IStatusBar, StatusBar>();
            DependencyService.Register<IVideoDownloadService, VideoDownloadService>();
            DependencyService.Register<ISqliteService, SqliteService>();

            DownloadBrodacast downloadBrodacast = new DownloadBrodacast();
            RegisterReceiver(downloadBrodacast, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ActionDownloadComplete));

            CrossMediaManager.Current.Init(this);

        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }


    }
```

Main theme is:

```
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
    <!-- As of Xamarin.Forms 4.6 the theme has moved into the Forms binary -->
    <!-- If you want to override anything you can do that here. -->
    <!-- Underneath are a couple of entries to get you started. -->

    <!-- Set theme colors from https://aka.ms/material-colors -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <!--<item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>-->
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <!--<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>-->
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <!--<item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>-->
    
  </style>
```

Comment: That looks suspiciously like a package name. It doesn't look to follow your application colour scheme. Could this be an Android setting?

Comment: Have you used a custom MainActivity class before in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: @Julian  I have added the Main Activity code for reference. It is customized to a certain extent.

Comment: @ChrisBD Yes, that's the package name. Previously it was the the label in the manifest. I removed that to try and fix the problem. It didnt

Comment: Please post your MainTheme, that you are applying on the Activity

Comment: *"Previously it was the the label in the manifest."* - You affected what was displayed, by removing something? Update question to show exactly what you removed, and from where. (I don't know what "label in the manifest" means.)

Comment: @Cheesebaron I have added the Main Theme. Its empty apart from the defaulted commented out code. I thought the issue might be here, but I cant figure out how to manipulate it.

Comment: MainTheme.Base, do you have `windowNoTitle` set to true and `windowActionBar` set to false?

Comment: I have just decided to import all the files into a new Maui project. That was quicker than trying to figure this one out.

Comment: @CraigChampion, I have the same problem. Could you maybe find out how the MainTheme of your original project differs from the one of a new project?